# Restrict acces to pages depending on cookie. Drupal

Tags: drupal

I want to restrict acces to certain pages, ex:
http:/www.something.com/hello/x

I need to restrict every page in "hello" path depending on whether a cookie is set. Any  idea of how to do this and where to put the code? Do i need to create a new module for me to do this?

Comment: how are generated pages in hello path?

Comment: There are only a few pages (less than 10) at hello/x. I want to restrict accees to all of them depending on a cookie.

Answer (score 1):

Try that in a custom module :

```
// Implements hook_init()
function mycustommodule_init() {
  if (drupal_match_path($_GET['q'], "hello/*")) {
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['my_cookie'])) {
      drupal_access_denied();
    }
  }
}
```